# Mono missing System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse(string,IFormatProvider)

Tags: c#, mono, couchdb, json.net

I'm currently getting the following error using the [Json.NET/Newtonsoft.JSON](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) library:

```
Missing method System.Numerics.BigInteger::Parse(string,IFormatProvider) in assembly
/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Numerics/4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll,
referenced in assembly ~/dev/Mono/Mercury/Mercury/bin/Debug/Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

This occurs every time that the Json retrieved from the couchDB database has a numeric value field. I discovered from searching that the method that the library is calling from System.Numerics isn't yet [implemented in Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Numerics/System.Numerics/BigInteger.cs#L1471).

The problem is that Json.NET is a dependency for another library that I'm using (WDK.API.CouchDB [3]).

**Is there any way I can circumvent this without tweaking the source of any of the libraries? Any Suggestions?**

**PS:** *I'm using Mono 3.0.6 and MonoDevelop 4.0.8, on Linux. I just started learning C# and this is my first project with it. I tried to search the topic on the web with no fruitful result.*

Thanks

[3] code.google.com/p/skitsanoswdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use a 4.5 version of Json.NET until Mono fix it.](http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/24176)

Comment: Yea, I think that will have to do. Nuget with Mono isn't very nice to use and I was avoiding to use older versions of the libraries. Thanks for the link, it went unnoticed by me.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not very practical when also referencing other libraries that require Json.NET as their dependency (and which I'd then have to remove from NuGet management in my project, as well).

Answer (score 18):

To fix this you can add a reference to `System.Numerics` and then set its property `Copy Local` to `true`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried any other method for converting strings to ints? I usually use Convert.ToInt32(//string) or if you want huge ints, then use Convert.ToInt64(//string)

Otherwise, check out. The TryParse() function is pretty handy:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-string-int

Comment: It wasn't I who was trying to make the conversions. It was being done by the Json.NET library, as I stated on the question.

Comment: I'm actually hitting the same problem, and the JSON.NET code actually does an Int64TryParse() first. It only tries the BigInteger.Parse if the Int64TryParse() throws an Overflow exception.

Answer (score -1):

If the method is not implemented, the best thing to do is **implement** it. Mono is an open source project. As such, if you cannot wait for the developers to implement something, you should step up and implement it, and send a pull request with your change.

Comment: This was not a very helpful response to C# beginner.

Comment: heh, I guess I missed the part about "beginner", where is it?

Comment: The part where OP says: "I just started learning C# and this is my first project with it."