# How to use the BigInteger class in MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, monodevelop, biginteger, linux-mint, system.numerics

I am using MonoDevelop in Linux Mint.

My problem is that I cannot find a the reference "System.Numerics", which otherwise I can easily find in VisualStudio when I use Windows.

I want particularly to use the BigInteger for larger values.
The closest thing I could find was this library: https://biginteger.codeplex.com/; which did not really work for me since I was not able to link it.

(This was the only thing I could find on here that was similar to my question, though did not work for me: [Mono missing System.Numerics.BigInteger.Parse(string,IFormatProvider)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175651/mono-missing-system-numerics-biginteger-parsestring-iformatprovider) . Any other proposal that would allow me to use numbers bigger than 20 digits is welcome.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Numerics` for your project:

[image]

#### Using:

```
using System.Numerics
```

#### Usage:

```
var bigInt = new BigInteger();
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Appreciate the photo added helped me quite a lot to distinguish where exactly I should search for it. My problem was that could not click on edit references due to the fact that i had not opened a solution. Thank you again.